Node.js app on Azure App Service fails to fetch secrets from Azure Key Vault: "No MSI credential available"
I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js application deployed on Azure App Service. The app is unable to fetch secrets from Azure Key Vault due to a credential error.
Environment:
Azure App Service (Linux)
Node.js 20 LTS
Azure Key Vault for storing secrets
Issue:
When the application attempts to retrieve secrets from Key Vault, it fails with the following error:
Error in loadSecrets function:
Error name: CredentialUnavailableError
Error message: ManagedIdentityCredential: Authentication failed. Message ManagedIdentityCredential - No MSI credential available
Here's the relevant part of my server.js file:
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");

const keyVaultName = process.env.KEY_VAULT_NAME;
const keyVaultUrl = `https://${keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net`;

async function loadSecrets() {
    try {
        require('dotenv').config();

        console.log('Starting loadSecrets function');
        console.log('NODE_ENV:', process.env.NODE_ENV);
        console.log('DATABASE_URL:', process.env.DATABASE_URL);
        console.log('KEY_VAULT_NAME:', process.env.KEY_VAULT_NAME);

        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            console.log('Production environment detected. Attempting to load secrets from Key Vault.');

            console.log('Creating DefaultAzureCredential...');
            const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            console.log('DefaultAzureCredential created successfully');

            const keyVaultUrl = `https://${process.env.KEY_VAULT_NAME}.vault.azure.net`;
            console.log('Key Vault URL:', keyVaultUrl);

            console.log('Creating SecretClient...');
            const secretClient = new SecretClient(keyVaultUrl, credential);
            console.log('SecretClient created successfully');

            console.log('Fetching secrets...');
            process.env.CLAUDE_API_KEY = (await secretClient.getSecret('CLAUDE-API-KEY')).value;
            console.log('CLAUDE-API-KEY fetched successfully');

            // ... [other secret fetching operations] ...

            console.log('All secrets loaded successfully from Key Vault');
        } else {
            console.log('Non-production environment. Skipping Key Vault secret loading.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in loadSecrets function:');
        console.error('Error name:', error.name);
        console.error('Error message:', error.message);
        // ... [additional error logging] ...
        throw error;
    }
}

// Load secrets before starting the server
loadSecrets().then(() => {
    // Server setup and route definitions...
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Failed to load secrets:', error);
    process.exit(1);
});

What I've Tried:
Verified that the system-assigned managed identity is enabled for the App Service.
Checked that the App Service's managed identity has the necessary permissions (Get, List) for secrets in the Key Vault access policies.
Confirmed that the KEY_VAULT_NAME environment variable is correctly set in the App Service configuration.
Tried using DefaultAzureCredential instead of ManagedIdentityCredential.
Verified that the secrets exist in Key Vault with the correct names.
Azure Configuration:
System-assigned managed identity is enabled for the App Service.
The App Service has the "Key Vault Secrets User" role assigned in the Key Vault's Access Control (IAM).
Key Vault is configured to use Azure role-based access control (RBAC).
Questions:
What could be causing the "No MSI credential available" error despite having the managed identity enabled?
Are there any additional configurations or permissions I might be missing?
How can I troubleshoot the managed identity authentication process?
Are there any known issues with Node.js 20 LTS and the Azure Identity SDK that could be causing this?
Is there a way to verify if the managed identity is correctly associated with the App Service at runtime?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You cannot use KeyVault with RBAC and Access Policies simultaneously. They are mutually exclusive.
You are saying:

Checked that the App Service's managed identity has the necessary
permissions (Get, List) for secrets in the Key Vault access policies

At the same time:

System-assigned managed identity is enabled for the App Service. The
App Service has the "Key Vault Secrets User" role assigned in the Key
Vault's Access Control (IAM). Key Vault is configured to use Azure
role-based access control (RBAC).

This is not possible. Assuming you've configured KV as RBAC-backed, you simply won't be able to see the Access Policies tab. Check the KeyVault you are connecting to.
Also,

No MSI credential available

indicates that AZURE credentials are not set in the App Sevice, which could be any of the following:

Identity is disabled.
System-assigned identity is enabled, but the code uses ManagedIdentityCredential
User-assigned identity is enabled, but the code uses DefaultAzureCredential

I followed the official guide and used parts of your code (see below) to deploy an app without issues, and it fetched the secret from the Key Vault. You are on the right track, but I recommend cleaning everything up and strictly following the cloud configuration.

Create an App Service. Enable System-assigned identity.
Create a Key Vault. Enable RBAC. Assign the identity from #1 a Key Vault Secrets User permission in the Key Vault's scope.
Deploy the code, but clean it up first (see my snippet below). You are testing the connectivity to the Key Vault, so stuff like "is_production" or reading a key vault name from the environment variable adds unnecessary complexity at this point and makes troubleshooting painful.



const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");
    
var app = express(); 
    
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential()
const client = new SecretClient("https://{put-your-name}.vault.azure.net", credential);
    
client
    .getSecret("{put-secret-name}")
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.value);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });




Thanks so much. I really am not sure what I'm doing wrong then. Went so far as to create a brand key vault and migrate things over, and using only RBAC, but still keep getting the error. Even went so crazy as to delete and redeploy my app. I'm convinced there's a configuration I am messing up.

did you try to deploy a sample app using the guide I shared? how do you deploy the app? I used VS code with Azure App Service extension.
